# Get Value from Key, Value is a List

Tags: java, list, hashmap

how i can get the Key from my Value?

My HashMap:

```
public static final Map<String, List<String>> Server = new HashMap<>();
```

my attempt:

```
  public static Object getKeyFromValue(String value) {
        for (Object o : Server.keySet()) {
             if (Server.get(o).equals(value)) {
                 return o;
             }
         }
         return null;
   }
```

It dosent work, because the Value is a List.

Comment: So if I understand correctly you want to return the list stored under a specific key? Or what is it you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`List#contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-):

```
if (Server.get(o).contains(value)) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate over a `Map`, if you need both the key and the value it's better to iterate over the `entrySet` rather than the `keySet`.

```
public static String getKeyFromValue(String value) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> e : Server.entrySet()) {
        if (e.getValue().contains(value)) {
            return e.getKey();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This should work, but there are 3 things I don't like about it (apart from `Server` beginning with a capital letter).

1. `contains` for many `List` implementations (including `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`) is slow, because it is a linear search. It may better to use `HashSet` instead.
2. If the `value` occurs in more than one list in the map, the returned key could be any of multiple answers. It may be better for the name of the method to indicate this (e.g. `getAnyKeyForValue`).
3. It may be preferable to return an `Optional<String>` rather than using `null` to mean that the value was not found.

A Java 8 solution, taking all of these points into consideration and taking advantage of parallelism would be

```
public static Optional<String> getAnyKeyForValue(String value) {
    return Server.entrySet()
                 .parallelStream()
                 .filter(e->e.getValue().contains(value))
                 .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                 .findAny();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just changing from equals to contains works. and all remains same

```
public static Object getKeyFromValue(String value) {
    for (Object o : Server.keySet()) {
        if (Server.get(o).contains(value)) {
             return o;
         }
     }
     return null;
}
```